# How to modify minified javascript file together with accompanying source map?

Tags: javascript, minify, source-maps

We have a 3rd party provided minified JavaScript file together with its source map. We also have the complete unminified source. We would like to modify one small part in the minified file to fix a bug, because we don't want to generate again a new minified file from the source file (it's a huge file) for such a small change. This will of course invalidate the accompanied source map. So the question is, (how) can we modify the minified JavaScript file, and have the modification reflect the source map file?

Comment: Don't go that way. Resist the temptation. The time you spend here asking the question and wait for some answers (if they come) could have been used to just re-minify from the source.

Comment: I thought there may be e.g. a plugin for an editor like vscode which allows you to modify the minified js while automatically modifying the .map file too.

Comment: Agree with @trincot. Minification should be one way. The moment you start directly modifying the minified JavaScript you now effectively have 2 source files that are out of sync instead of just one true source file